How to filter column in the jQuery Datatable
When the below code runs, it will display a datatable with values on it. There is a filter icon on each header column. Click on the filter icon on the header column, it will drop down a filter menu with check box. This filter drop down menu will display all the values in the respective column. After filtering the first column, the data in the datatable is filtered and have less records in it. Then second time when we click on the "Position" filter icon on its header column, it is showing all the values which is not in that "Position" column in the filter drop down list.

I want to have only visible column datas in the respective column when displaying the filter menu drop down for that column. How to do it ?
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
   <title>Jquery DataTable with Custom Filter</title>
   <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" 
    type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen,projection" />
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.7/css/materialize.min.css" />
   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.7/js/materialize.min.js"> 
</script>
<style>
    table.dataTable th {
        border-bottom: 1px solid #333;
        border-right: 1px solid #333;
    }

    table.dataTable td {
        border-bottom: 1px solid #333;
        border-right: 1px solid #333;
    }

    .filterIcon {
        height: 16px;
        width: 16px;
    }

    .modalFilter {
        display: none;
        height: auto;
        background: #FFF;
        border: solid 1px #ccc;
        padding: 8px;
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 1001;
    }

        .modalFilter .modal-content {
            max-height: 250px;
            overflow-y: auto;
        }

        .modalFilter .modal-footer {
            background: #FFF;
            height: 35px;
            padding-top: 6px;
        }

        .modalFilter .btn {
            padding: 0 1em;
            height: 28px;
            line-height: 28px;
            text-transform: none;
        }

    #mask {
        display: none;
        background: transparent;
        position: fixed;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        z-index: 1;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        opacity: 1000;
    }
</style>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var dataSet = [
["Tiger Nixon", "System Architect", "Edinburgh", "5421", "2011/04/25", "$320,800"],
["Garrett Winters", "Accountant", "Tokyo", "8422", "2011/07/25", "$170,750"],
["Ashton Cox", "Junior Technical Author", "San Francisco", "1562", "2009/01/12", "$86,000"],
["Cedric Kelly", "Senior Javascript Developer", "Edinburgh", "6224", "2012/03/29", "$433,060"],
["Airi Satou", "Accountant", "Tokyo", "5407", "2008/11/28", "$162,700"]    
        ];

        $('#example').DataTable({
            data: dataSet,
            "lengthMenu": [[5, 10, 50, -1], [5, 10, 50, "All"]],
            "pageLength": 10,
            columns: [
        { title: "Name" },
        { title: "Position" },
        { title: "Office" },
        { title: "Extn." },
        { title: "Start date" },
        { title: "Salary" }
            ],

            initComplete: function () {
                configFilter(this, [0, 1, 2, 4]);
            }
        });

        $('#example_length,#example_filter').hide();
    });

    //This function initializes the content inside the filter modal
    function configFilter($this, colArray) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            var tableName = $this[0].id;
            var columns = $this.api().columns();
            $.each(colArray, function (i, arg) {
                $('#' + tableName + ' th:eq(' + arg + ')').append('<img src="http://www.icone-png.com/png/39/38556.png" class="filterIcon" onclick="showFilter(event,\'' + tableName + '_' + arg + '\')" />');
            });

            var template = '<div class="modalFilter">' +
                             '<div class="modal-content">' +
                             '{0}</div>' +
                             '<div class="modal-footer">' +
                                 '<a href="#!" onclick="clearFilter(this, {1}, \'{2}\');"  class=" btn left waves-effect waves-light">Clear</a>' +
                                 '<a href="#!" onclick="performFilter(this, {1}, \'{2}\');"  class=" btn right waves-effect waves-light">Ok</a>' +
                             '</div>' +
                         '</div>';
            $.each(colArray, function (index, value) {
                columns.every(function (i) {
                    if (value === i) {
                        var column = this, content = '<input type="text" class="filterSearchText" onkeyup="filterValues(this)" /> <br/>';
                        var columnName = $(this.header()).text().replace(/\s+/g, "_");
                        var distinctArray = [];
                        column.data().each(function (d, j) {
                            if (distinctArray.indexOf(d) == -1) {
                                var id = tableName + "_" + columnName + "_" + j; // onchange="formatValues(this,' + value + ');
                                content += '<div><input type="checkbox" value="' + d + '"  id="' + id + '"/><label for="' + id + '"> ' + d + '</label></div>';
                                distinctArray.push(d);
                            }
                        });
                        var newTemplate = $(template.replace('{0}', content).replace('{1}', value).replace('{1}', value).replace('{2}', tableName).replace('{2}', tableName));
                        $('body').append(newTemplate);
                        modalFilterArray[tableName + "_" + value] = newTemplate;
                        content = '';
                    }
                });
            });
        }, 50);
    }
    var modalFilterArray = {};
    //User to show the filter modal
    function showFilter(e, index) {
        $('.modalFilter').hide();
        $(modalFilterArray[index]).css({ left: 0, top: 0 });
        var th = $(e.target).parent();
        var pos = th.offset();
        console.log(th);
        $(modalFilterArray[index]).width(th.width() * 0.75);
        $(modalFilterArray[index]).css({ 'left': pos.left, 'top': pos.top });
        $(modalFilterArray[index]).show();
        $('#mask').show();
        e.stopPropagation();
    }

    //This function is to use the searchbox to filter the checkbox
    function filterValues(node) {
        var searchString = $(node).val().toUpperCase().trim();
        var rootNode = $(node).parent();
        if (searchString == '') {
            rootNode.find('div').show();
        } else {
            rootNode.find("div").hide();
            rootNode.find("div:contains('" + searchString + "')").show();
        }
    }

    //Execute the filter on the table for a given column
    function performFilter(node, i, tableId) {
        var rootNode = $(node).parent().parent();
        var searchString = '', counter = 0;

        rootNode.find('input:checkbox').each(function (index, checkbox) {
            if (checkbox.checked) {
                searchString += (counter == 0) ? checkbox.value : '|' + checkbox.value;
                counter++;
            }
        });
        $('#' + tableId).DataTable().column(i).search(
            searchString,
            true, false
        ).draw();
        rootNode.hide();
        $('#mask').hide();
    }

    //Removes the filter from the table for a given column
    function clearFilter(node, i, tableId) {
        var rootNode = $(node).parent().parent();
        rootNode.find(".filterSearchText").val('');
        rootNode.find('input:checkbox').each(function (index, checkbox) {
            checkbox.checked = false;
            $(checkbox).parent().show();
        });
        $('#' + tableId).DataTable().column(i).search(
            '',
            true, false
        ).draw();
        rootNode.hide();
        $('#mask').hide();
    }
  </script>
  </head>
 <body>
   <div id="mask"></div>
   <h3>Jquery DataTable with custom filter</h3>
   <table id="example" class="bordered material-table centered striped green lighten- 
   1"></table>
  </body>
</html>


This question is similar to: Dynamically populate second drop down menu based on first selection. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@DanielManta sir, question updated.

UPDATE
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
    Layout = null;
}

@model IEnumerable<WebApplication1.Models.Employee>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Jquery DataTable with Custom Filter</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen,projection" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.7/css/materialize.min.css" />
    <script src="~/js/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/jquery.datatables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
        <style>
        table.dataTable th {
            border-bottom: 1px solid #333;
            border-right: 1px solid #333;
        }

        table.dataTable td {
            border-bottom: 1px solid #333;
            border-right: 1px solid #333;
        }

        .filterIcon {
            height: 16px;
            width: 16px;
        }

        .modalFilter {
            display: none;
            height: auto;
            background: #FFF;
            border: solid 1px #ccc;
            padding: 8px;
            position: absolute;
            z-index: 1001;
        }

        .modalFilter .modal-content {
            max-height: 250px;
            overflow-y: auto;
        }

        .modalFilter .modal-footer {
            background: #FFF;
            height: 35px;
            padding-top: 6px;
        }

        .modalFilter .btn {
            padding: 0 1em;
            height: 28px;
            line-height: 28px;
            text-transform: none;
        }

        #mask {
            display: none;
            background: transparent;
            position: fixed;
            left: 0;
            top: 0;
            z-index: 1;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            opacity: 1000;
        }
    </style>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var dataSet = [
                ["Tiger Nixon", "System Architect", "Edinburgh", "5421", "2011/04/25", "$320,800"],
                ["Garrett Winters", "Accountant", "Tokyo", "8422", "2011/07/25", "$170,750"],
                ["Ashton Cox", "Junior Technical Author", "San Francisco", "1562", "2009/01/12", "$86,000"],
                ["Cedric Kelly", "Senior Javascript Developer", "Edinburgh", "6224", "2012/03/29", "$433,060"],
                ["Airi Satou", "Accountant", "Tokyo", "5407", "2008/11/28", "$162,700"]
            ];

            $('#example').DataTable({
                data: dataSet,
                "lengthMenu": [[5, 10, 50, -1], [5, 10, 50, "All"]],
                "pageLength": 10,
                columns: [
                    { title: "Name" },
                    { title: "Position" },
                    { title: "Office" },
                    { title: "Extn." },
                    { title: "Start date" },
                    { title: "Salary" }
                ],

                initComplete: function () {
                    configFilter(this, [0, 1, 2, 4]);
                }
            });

            $('#example_length,#example_filter').hide();
        });

        //This function initializes the content inside the filter modal
        function configFilter($this, colArray) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                var tableName = $this[0].id;
                var columns = $this.api().columns();
                $.each(colArray, function (i, arg) {
                    $('#' + tableName + ' th:eq(' + arg + ')').append('<img src="https://localhost:7059/38556.png" class="filterIcon" onclick="showFilter(event,\'' + tableName + '_' + arg + '\')" />');
                });

                var template = '<div class="modalFilter">' +
                                 '<div class="modal-content">' +
                                 '{0}</div>' +
                                 '<div class="modal-footer">' +
                                     '<a href="#!" onclick="clearFilter(this, {1}, \'{2}\');"  class=" btn left waves-effect waves-light">Clear</a>' +
                                     '<a href="#!" onclick="performFilter(this, {1}, \'{2}\');"  class=" btn right waves-effect waves-light">Ok</a>' +
                                 '</div>' +
                             '</div>';
                $.each(colArray, function (index, value) {
                    columns.every(function (i) {
                        if (value === i) {
                            var column = this, content = '<input type="text" class="filterSearchText" onkeyup="filterValues(this)" /> <br/>';
                            var columnName = $(this.header()).text().replace(/\s+/g, "_");
                            var distinctArray = [];
                            column.data().each(function (d, j) {
                                if (distinctArray.indexOf(d) == -1) {
                                    var id = tableName + "_" + columnName + "_" + j;
                                    content += '<div><input type="checkbox" value="' + d + '"  id="' + id + '"/><label for="' + id + '"> ' + d + '</label></div>';
                                    distinctArray.push(d);
                                }
                            });
                            var newTemplate = $(template.replace('{0}', content).replace('{1}', value).replace('{1}', value).replace('{2}', tableName).replace('{2}', tableName));
                            $('body').append(newTemplate);
                            modalFilterArray[tableName + "_" + value] = newTemplate;
                            content = '';
                        }
                    });
                });
            }, 50);
        }

        var modalFilterArray = {};

        //User to show the filter modal
        function showFilter(e, index) {
            var table = $('#' + index.split('_')[0]).DataTable();
            var columnIdx = parseInt(index.split('_')[1]);
            var column = table.column(columnIdx);

            
            var filterContainer = $(modalFilterArray[index]);
            var content = '<input type="text" class="filterSearchText" onkeyup="filterValues(this)" /> <br/>';
            var distinctArray = [];

            
            table.rows({ search: 'applied' }).every(function (rowIdx, tableLoop, rowLoop) {
                var data = this.data()[columnIdx];
                if (distinctArray.indexOf(data) == -1) {
                    var id = index + "_" + rowIdx;
                    content += '<div><input type="checkbox" value="' + data + '" id="' + id + '"/><label for="' + id + '"> ' + data + '</label></div>';
                    distinctArray.push(data);
                }
            });

            
            filterContainer.find('.modal-content').html(content);

            
            $('.modalFilter').hide();
            var th = $(e.target).parent();
            var pos = th.offset();
            filterContainer.width(th.width() * 0.75);
            filterContainer.css({ 'left': pos.left, 'top': pos.top }).show();
            $('#mask').show();
            e.stopPropagation();
        }

        //This function is to use the searchbox to filter the checkbox
        function filterValues(node) {
            var searchString = $(node).val().toUpperCase().trim();
            var rootNode = $(node).parent();
            if (searchString == '') {
                rootNode.find('div').show();
            } else {
                rootNode.find("div").hide();
                rootNode.find("div:contains('" + searchString + "')").show();
            }
        }

        //Execute the filter on the table for a given column
        function performFilter(node, i, tableId) {
            var rootNode = $(node).parent().parent();
            var searchString = '', counter = 0;

            rootNode.find('input:checkbox').each(function (index, checkbox) {
                if (checkbox.checked) {
                    searchString += (counter == 0) ? checkbox.value : '|' + checkbox.value;
                    counter++;
                }
            });
            $('#' + tableId).DataTable().column(i).search(
                searchString,
                true, false
            ).draw();
            rootNode.hide();
            $('#mask').hide();
        }

        //Removes the filter from the table for a given column
        function clearFilter(node, i, tableId) {
            var rootNode = $(node).parent().parent();
            rootNode.find(".filterSearchText").val('');
            rootNode.find('input:checkbox').each(function (index, checkbox) {
                checkbox.checked = false;
                $(checkbox).parent().show();
            });
            $('#' + tableId).DataTable().column(i).search(
                '',
                true, false
            ).draw();
            rootNode.hide();
            $('#mask').hide();
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="mask"></div>
    <h3>Jquery DataTable with custom filter</h3>
    <table id="example" class="bordered material-table centered striped green lighten-1"></table>
</body>
</html>


After testing, below code works in my side. For testing, I change the script source and the icon url.
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
    Layout = null;
}

@model IEnumerable<WebApplication1.Models.Employee>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Jquery DataTable with Custom Filter</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen,projection" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.7/css/materialize.min.css" />
    <script src="~/js/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/jquery.datatables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        table.dataTable th {
            border-bottom: 1px solid #333;
            border-right: 1px solid #333;
        }

        table.dataTable td {
            border-bottom: 1px solid #333;
            border-right: 1px solid #333;
        }

        .filterIcon {
            height: 16px;
            width: 16px;
        }

        .modalFilter {
            display: none;
            height: auto;
            background: #FFF;
            border: solid 1px #ccc;
            padding: 8px;
            position: absolute;
            z-index: 1001;
        }

            .modalFilter .modal-content {
                max-height: 250px;
                overflow-y: auto;
            }

            .modalFilter .modal-footer {
                background: #FFF;
                height: 35px;
                padding-top: 6px;
            }

            .modalFilter .btn {
                padding: 0 1em;
                height: 28px;
                line-height: 28px;
                text-transform: none;
            }

        #mask {
            display: none;
            background: transparent;
            position: fixed;
            left: 0;
            top: 0;
            z-index: 1;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            opacity: 1000;
        }
    </style>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var dataSet = [
        @foreach (var employee in Model)
        {
            @Html.Raw($"[\"{employee.Name}\", \"{employee.Position}\", \"{employee.Office}\", \"{employee.Extn}\", \"{employee.StartDate}\", \"{employee.Salary}\"],")
        }
                    ];

            $('#example').DataTable({
                data: dataSet,
                "lengthMenu": [[5, 10, 50, -1], [5, 10, 50, "All"]],
                "pageLength": 10,
                columns: [
                    { title: "Name" },
                    { title: "Position" },
                    { title: "Office" },
                    { title: "Extn." },
                    { title: "Start date" },
                    { title: "Salary" }
                ],

                initComplete: function () {
                    configFilter(this, [0, 1, 2, 4]);
                }
            });

            $('#example_length,#example_filter').hide();
        });

        // This function initializes the content inside the filter modal
        function configFilter($this, colArray) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                var tableName = $this[0].id;
                var columns = $this.api().columns();
                $.each(colArray, function (i, arg) {
                    $('#' + tableName + ' th:eq(' + arg + ')').append('<img src="https://localhost:7059/38556.png" class="filterIcon" onclick="showFilter(event,\'' + tableName + '_' + arg + '\')" />');
                });

                var template = '<div class="modalFilter">' +
                    '<div class="modal-content">' +
                    '{0}</div>' +
                    '<div class="modal-footer">' +
                    '<a href="#!" onclick="clearFilter(this, {1}, \'{2}\');"  class=" btn left waves-effect waves-light">Clear</a>' +
                    '<a href="#!" onclick="performFilter(this, {1}, \'{2}\');"  class=" btn right waves-effect waves-light">Ok</a>' +
                    '</div>' +
                    '</div>';
                $.each(colArray, function (index, value) {
                    columns.every(function (i) {
                        if (value === i) {
                            var column = this, content = '<input type="text" class="filterSearchText" onkeyup="filterValues(this)" /> <br/>';
                            var columnName = $(this.header()).text().replace(/\s+/g, "_");
                            var distinctArray = [];
                            column.data().each(function (d, j) {
                                if (distinctArray.indexOf(d) == -1) {
                                    var id = tableName + "_" + columnName + "_" + j;
                                    content += '<div><input type="checkbox" value="' + d + '"  id="' + id + '"/><label for="' + id + '"> ' + d + '</label></div>';
                                    distinctArray.push(d);
                                }
                            });
                            var newTemplate = $(template.replace('{0}', content).replace('{1}', value).replace('{1}', value).replace('{2}', tableName).replace('{2}', tableName));
                            $('body').append(newTemplate);
                            modalFilterArray[tableName + "_" + value] = newTemplate;
                            content = '';
                        }
                    });
                });
            }, 50);
        }
        var modalFilterArray = {};
        // User to show the filter modal
        function showFilter(e, index) {
            $('.modalFilter').hide();
            $(modalFilterArray[index]).css({ left: 0, top: 0 });
            var th = $(e.target).parent();
            var pos = th.offset();
            console.log(th);
            $(modalFilterArray[index]).width(th.width() * 0.75);
            $(modalFilterArray[index]).css({ 'left': pos.left, 'top': pos.top });
            $(modalFilterArray[index]).show();
            $('#mask').show();
            e.stopPropagation();
        }

        // This function is to use the searchbox to filter the checkbox
        function filterValues(node) {
            var searchString = $(node).val().toUpperCase().trim();
            var rootNode = $(node).parent();
            if (searchString == '') {
                rootNode.find('div').show();
            } else {
                rootNode.find("div").hide();
                rootNode.find("div:contains('" + searchString + "')").show();
            }
        }

        // Execute the filter on the table for a given column
        function performFilter(node, i, tableId) {
            var rootNode = $(node).parent().parent();
            var searchString = '', counter = 0;

            rootNode.find('input:checkbox').each(function (index, checkbox) {
                if (checkbox.checked) {
                    searchString += (counter == 0) ? checkbox.value : '|' + checkbox.value;
                    counter++;
                }
            });
            $('#' + tableId).DataTable().column(i).search(
                searchString,
                true, false
            ).draw();
            rootNode.hide();
            $('#mask').hide();
        }

        // Removes the filter from the table for a given column
        function clearFilter(node, i, tableId) {
            var rootNode = $(node).parent().parent();
            rootNode.find(".filterSearchText").val('');
            rootNode.find('input:checkbox').each(function (index, checkbox) {
                checkbox.checked = false;
                $(checkbox).parent().show();
            });
            $('#' + tableId).DataTable().column(i).search(
                '',
                true, false
            ).draw();
            rootNode.hide();
            $('#mask').hide();
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="mask"></div>
    <h3>Jquery DataTable with custom filter</h3>
    <table id="example" class="bordered material-table centered striped green lighten-1"></table>
</body>
</html>


This is not working. The filter drop down menu for a column should show only the visible column values of that column. Not invisible column values. Thanks for your effort. Please help me.

Hi @KitKat Please check it and change the scripts source and the icon link.

Hi @Jason Pan. Yes the updated one is working. But there is a problem. After filtering, when we click on "CLEAR" button, it should go back to Original state. That is not happening here. Please help me with that also.

@KitKat The current code works well without the problem you mentioned. First, suppose we filter by Name, then clicking Clear in the Name pop-up window will restore the previous data.

@KitKat Suppose that after filtering the data in Name, click Clear in Position to restore all the data. That would be a disaster and your users would need to filter the data again.

@KitKat Therefore, the Clear in each filter only restores the current data.

@KitKat Maybe I misunderstood what you meant. Please provide detailed screenshots to explain. Thanks for your patience.

Hi @Jason Pan. Thanks very much for your help.

Hi @Jason Pan - The above code is not working with List() loaded from DB. I have posted the issue in here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78882883/filter-menu-is-not-working-with-jquery-datatable. Please help me once again.

@KitKat Will check it tomorrow

Hi @KitKat, please set a break point and let us know what returned from asp.net core backend.

Hi @Jason Pan sir, it is not taking any data from DB. For the time being, the datasource record is hardcoded. In the question, I have shown a controller method which gets the data source data for the datatable. This is the link of my new question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78882883/filter-menu-is-not-working-with-jquery-datatable please help me sir

Hi @Jason Pan I posted new question regarding new issue here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78898051/jquery-datatable-column-filter-search-is-not-working Please help
