Filter menu is not working with jQuery DataTable
I am dynamically loading data into the jQuery datatable using ajax method. The filter menu is droping down when clicking on the filter icon in datatable column header and it shows always "undefined". This project is a ASP.Net Core MVC C# app. The code is shown below:
   @model Models.DOOR_MANAGEMENT

   @{
      ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
    }

   <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
  <head>

<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen,projection" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.7/css/materialize.min.css" />
<script src="~/js/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/jquery.datatables.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

<style>
    table.dataTable th {
        border-bottom: 1px solid #333;
        border-right: 1px solid #333;
    }

    table.dataTable td {
        border-bottom: 1px solid #333;
        border-right: 1px solid #333;
    }

    .filterIcon {
        height: 16px;
        width: 16px;
    }

    .modalFilter {
        display: none;
        height: auto;
        background: #FFF;
        border: solid 1px #ccc;
        padding: 8px;
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 1001;
    }

        .modalFilter .modal-content {
            max-height: 250px;
            overflow-y: auto;
        }

        .modalFilter .modal-footer {
            background: #FFF;
            height: 35px;
            padding-top: 6px;
        }

        .modalFilter .btn {
            padding: 0 1em;
            height: 28px;
            line-height: 28px;
            text-transform: none;
        }

    #mask {
        display: none;
        background: transparent;
        position: fixed;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        z-index: 1;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        opacity: 1000;
    }
   </style>

    <script>

    $(document).ready(function (){

        $("#example").DataTable({
        serverSide: true,
        sortable: true,
        filter: true,
        searchDelay: 1000,
        lengthMenu: [[5, 10, 50, -1], [5, 10, 50, "All"]],
        language: { searchPlaceholder: "Brand, Buying Group" },
        scrollCollapse: true,
        ajax: {
            url: '/DOOR_MANAGEMENT/LoadDoors',
            type: 'GET',
            datatype: 'json',
            headers: { 'RequestVerificationToken': 'your json token' },
            data: (d) => {                    
                return { draw: d.draw, start: d.start, length: d.length, search: d.search.value, FilterByColumn: d.columns[d.order[0].column].data, ASC_DSEC: d.order[0].dir }
            },
            beforeSend: () => { ShowLoader(); },
            complete: () => { HideLoader(); },
            dataSrc: (json) => {
                json = json.data;                    
                for (var i = 0, ien = json.length; i < ien; i++) {

                    json[i]['sites'] = '<button style="height:25px;width:60px"> Site </button>';                                                                    
                }
                return json;
            }
        },
        columnDefs: [{ className: "dt-center", targets: [1,2,3] }],
        columns: [
            { data: 'DOOR_ID', title: 'DOOR ID', autoWidth: false, visible: false },                
            { data: 'BRAND', title: 'Brand Code', autoWidth: true, searchable: true },
            { data: 'BUYING_GROUP', title: 'Buying Group', autoWidth: true },
            { data: 'SETTING_NAME', title: 'Setting Name', autoWidth: true },
            { data: 'sites', title: 'Site(s)', autoWidth: true, orderable: false },                            
            { data: 'TRACKING_WEEKS', title: 'Tracking Weeks', autoWidth: true }                             
        ],

         initComplete: function () {
                configFilter(this, [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]);
            }               
                        
        });// datatable

         $('#example_length,#example_filter').hide();
    });

   function configFilter($this, colArray) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            var tableName = $this[0].id;
            var columns = $this.api().columns();
            $.each(colArray, function (i, arg) {
                $('#' + tableName + ' th:eq(' + arg + ')').append('<img src="http://www.icone-png.com/png/39/38556.png" class="filterIcon" onclick="showFilter(event,\'' + tableName + '_' + arg + '\')" />');
            });

            var template = '<div class="modalFilter">' +
                '<div class="modal-content">' +
                '{0}</div>' +
                '<div class="modal-footer">' +
                '<a href="#!" onclick="clearFilter(this, {1}, \'{2}\');"  class=" btn left waves-effect waves-light">Clear</a>' +
                '<a href="#!" onclick="performFilter(this, {1}, \'{2}\');"  class=" btn right waves-effect waves-light">Ok</a>' +
                '</div>' +
                '</div>';
            $.each(colArray, function (index, value) {
                columns.every(function (i) {
                    if (value === i) {
                        
                        var column = this, content = '<input type="text" class="filterSearchText" onkeyup="filterValues(this)" /> <br/>';                            
                        var columnName = $(this.header()).text().replace(/\s+/g, "_");
                        var distinctArray = [];
                        column.data().each(function (d, j) {
                            if (distinctArray.indexOf(d) == -1) {
                                var id = tableName + "_" + columnName + "_" + j;
                                content += '<div><input type="checkbox" value="' + d + '"  id="' + id + '"/><label for="' + id + '"> ' + d + '</label></div>';
                                distinctArray.push(d);
                            }
                        });
                        var newTemplate = $(template.replace('{0}', content).replace('{1}', value).replace('{1}', value).replace('{2}', tableName).replace('{2}', tableName));
                        $('body').append(newTemplate);
                        modalFilterArray[tableName + "_" + value] = newTemplate;
                        content = '';
                    }
                });
            });
        }, 50);
    }


   var modalFilterArray = {};

    function showFilter(e, index) {
        var table = $('#' + index.split('_')[0]).DataTable();            
        var columnIdx = parseInt(index.split('_')[1]);            
        var column = table.column(columnIdx);            
        var filterContainer = $(modalFilterArray[index]);
        var content = '<input type="text" class="filterSearchText" onkeyup="filterValues(this)" /> <br/>';
        var distinctArray = [];
        table.rows({ search: 'applied' }).every(function (rowIdx, tableLoop, rowLoop) {
            var data = this.data()[columnIdx];
            if (distinctArray.indexOf(data) == -1) {
                var id = index + "_" + rowIdx;                   
                content += '<div><input type="checkbox" value="' + data + '" id="' + id + '"/><label for="' + id + '"> ' + data + '</label></div>';
                distinctArray.push(data);
            }
        });

        filterContainer.find('.modal-content').html(content);

        $('.modalFilter').hide();
        var th = $(e.target).parent();
        var pos = th.offset();
        filterContainer.width(th.width() * 0.75);
        filterContainer.css({ 'left': pos.left, 'top': pos.top }).show();
        $('#mask').show();
        e.stopPropagation();
    }

    function filterValues(node) {
        var searchString = $(node).val(); //.toUpperCase().trim();
        var rootNode = $(node).parent();
        if (searchString == '') {
            rootNode.find('div').show();
        } else {
            rootNode.find("div").hide();
            rootNode.find("div:contains('" + searchString + "')").show();
        }
    }

    function performFilter(node, i, tableId) {
        var rootNode = $(node).parent().parent();
        var searchString = '', counter = 0;

        rootNode.find('input:checkbox').each(function (index, checkbox) {
            if (checkbox.checked) {
                searchString += (counter == 0) ? checkbox.value : '|' + checkbox.value;
                counter++;
            }
        });
        $('#' + tableId).DataTable().column(i).search(
            searchString,
            true, false
        ).draw();
        rootNode.hide();
        $('#mask').hide();
    }

    function clearFilter(node, i, tableId) {
        var rootNode = $(node).parent().parent();
        rootNode.find(".filterSearchText").val('');
        rootNode.find('input:checkbox').each(function (index, checkbox) {
            checkbox.checked = false;
            $(checkbox).parent().show();
        });
        $('#' + tableId).DataTable().column(i).search(
            '',
            true, false
        ).draw();
        rootNode.hide();
        $('#mask').hide();
    }                                 

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="mask"></div>    
<table id="example" class="bordered material-table centered striped green lighten-1"> 
</table>
</body>
</html>

And the method in the controller is as shown below:
   public IActionResult LoadDoors(int draw = 1, int start = 0, int length = 10, string search = "", string FilterByColumn = "", string ASC_DSEC = "")
    {
        List<DOOR_MANAGEMENT> ListData = new List<DOOR_MANAGEMENT>();
        int recordsTotal = 0;
        
        DOOR_MANAGEMENT dm = new DOOR_MANAGEMENT();
        dm.DOOR_ID = 1;            
        dm.BRAND = "BM";
        dm.BUYING_GROUP = "SEPHIA USA";
        dm.SETTING_NAME = "Settings1";            
        dm.DATAMODEL = 13;
        dm.TRACKING_WEEKS = 1;       
        
        DOOR_MANAGEMENT dm1 = new DOOR_MANAGEMENT();
        dm1.DOOR_ID = 2;           
        dm1.BRAND = "NB";
        dm1.BUYING_GROUP = "JOHN USA";
        dm1.SETTING_NAME = "Settings2";           
        dm1.DATAMODEL = 16;
        dm1.TRACKING_WEEKS = 14;           

        DOOR_MANAGEMENT dm11 = new DOOR_MANAGEMENT();
        dm11.DOOR_ID = 3;            
        dm11.BRAND = "JA";
        dm11.BUYING_GROUP = "Elms UK";
        dm11.SETTING_NAME = "Settings 3";           
        dm11.DATAMODEL = 17;
        dm11.TRACKING_WEEKS = 45;

        ListData.Add(dm);
        ListData.Add(dm1);
        ListData.Add(dm11);

        recordsTotal = ListData.Count();                    

        var jsonData = new { draw = draw, recordsFiltered = recordsTotal, recordsTotal = recordsTotal, data = ListData };
        return Ok(jsonData);
    }

The Model DOOR_MANAGEMENT is shown below:
    public class DOOR_MANAGEMENT
     {
       public int DOOR_ID { get; set; }       
       public string BRAND { get; set; }
       public string BUYING_GROUP { get;set; }
       public string SETTING_NAME { get;set; }
       public int? DATAMODEL { get;set; } 
       public int? TRACKING_WEEKS { get;set;}                                      
     }

The above code will work if it is hardcoded DataSet. But when dynamically loading data from database as
List<DOOR_MANAGEMENT>( ), the filter menu shows "undefined".
I figured it out the place of issue:
   function showFilter(e, index) {
        var table = $('#' + index.split('_')[0]).DataTable();            
        var columnIdx = parseInt(index.split('_')[1]);            
        var column = table.column(columnIdx);            
        var filterContainer = $(modalFilterArray[index]);
        var content = '<input type="text" class="filterSearchText" onkeyup="filterValues(this)" /> <br/>';
        var distinctArray = [];
        table.rows({ search: 'applied' }).every(function (rowIdx, tableLoop, rowLoop) {
            var data = this.data()[columnIdx];
            alert(data); **// HERE IS THE PROBLEM. Data is undefined.**
  .........................

Please help me.

this.data() returns an object and you need to access its properties dynamically based on the column index, you'll want to map the column index to the corresponding property name.
Modify your like below:
var columnMapping = {
    0: 'brand',
    1: 'buyinG_GROUP',
    2: 'settinG_NAME',
    3: 'sites',
    4: 'trackinG_WEEKS'
};
var propertyName = columnMapping[columnIdx];

 table.rows({ search: 'applied' }).every(function (rowIdx, tableLoop, rowLoop) {
    
    var data = this.data()[propertyName];
    alert(data);

The property name depends on the response json you get. Please check your response json below:
dataSrc: (json) => {
    json = json.data;
    for (var i = 0, ien = json.length; i < ien; i++) {

        json[i]['sites'] = '<button style="height:25px;width:60px"> Site </button>';
    }
    console.log(json);   //F12 in the browser and check the Console panel
    return json;
}

The response json in my side is like below:

DataTable in asp.net core render the json data with a lowercase initial letter by default, so also need modify the columns like below:
columns: [
    { data: 'dooR_ID', title: 'DOOR ID', autoWidth: false, visible: false },
    { data: 'brand', title: 'Brand Code', autoWidth: true, searchable: true },
    { data: 'buyinG_GROUP', title: 'Buying Group', autoWidth: true },
    { data: 'settinG_NAME', title: 'Setting Name', autoWidth: true },
    { data: 'sites', title: 'Site(s)', autoWidth: true, orderable: false },
    { data: 'trackinG_WEEKS', title: 'Tracking Weeks', autoWidth: true }
],


Hi @Rena - The undefined error is gone and I am able to list out the filter menu with correct data in it. Thanks. But the problem is when I selected the checkbox and click OK, the datatable is not filtering. After clicking OK in the filter menu, nothing happens. Could you please check that and solve it ?

Hi @KitKat, I think it should be a new issue. For the SO policy, I suggest you can post a new thread with your detailed code with explanations.

Hi @Rena. Thanks for the help. But I posted the new question for filtering Datatable here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78898051/jquery-datatable-column-filter-search-is-not-working. Please help me.
