jQuery Datatable column filter search is not working
I am working on a ASP.Net Core MVC C# app (Visual Studio 2022) and it uses jQuery datatable. I am using ajax call to load data from database. On each column header in the datatable, there is a filter icon clicking on which will drop down a filter menu which contains the column data with check box as shown below.
            [![enter image description here][1]][1]

The problem is when selecting 1 or more checked box in the filter menu and click OK, the datatable should filter the data in it. But the filter search is not working in my code. Here is the code that I am using in my ASP.Net Core MVC app.
In the Index.cshtml:
          @model AMD_WEB.Models.DoorDetails

         @{
              ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
          }

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>

    <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" 
          type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen,projection" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.7/css/materialize.min.css" />
<script src="~/js/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/jquery.datatables.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/materialize.min.js"></script>   

<style>
    table.dataTable th {
        border-bottom: 1px solid #333;
        border-right: 1px solid #333;
    }

    table.dataTable td {
        border-bottom: 1px solid #333;
        border-right: 1px solid #333;
    }

    .filterIcon {
        height: 16px;
        width: 16px;
    }

    .modalFilter {
        display: none;
        height: auto;
        background: #FFF;
        border: solid 1px #ccc;
        padding: 8px;
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 1001;
    }

        .modalFilter .modal-content {
            max-height: 250px;
            overflow-y: auto;
        }

        .modalFilter .modal-footer {
            background: #FFF;
            height: 35px;
            padding-top: 6px;
        }

        .modalFilter .btn {
            padding: 0 1em;
            height: 28px;
            line-height: 28px;
            text-transform: none;
        }

    #mask {
        display: none;
        background: transparent;
        position: fixed;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        z-index: 1;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        opacity: 1000;
    }
</style>

<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#example").DataTable({
            serverSide: true,
            sortable: true,
            filter: true,
            searchDelay: 1000,                
            lengthMenu: [[5, 10, 50, -1], [5, 10, 50, "All"]],
            language: { searchPlaceholder: "Brand, Buying Group" },
            scrollCollapse: true,
            ajax: {
                url: '/DOOR_MANAGEMENT/LoadDoors',
                type: 'GET',
                datatype: 'json',
                headers: { 'RequestVerificationToken': 'your json token' },
                data: (d) => {
                    return { draw: d.draw, start: d.start, length: d.length, search: d.search.value, FilterByColumn: d.columns[d.order[0].column].data, ASC_DSEC: d.order[0].dir }
                },
                beforeSend: () => { ShowLoader(); },
                complete: () => { HideLoader(); },
                dataSrc: (json) => {
                    json = json.data;
                    for (var i = 0, ien = json.length; i < ien; i++) {

                        json[i]['sites'] = '<button style="height:25px;width:60px"> Site </button>';
                    }
                    return json;
                }
            },
            columnDefs: [{ className: "dt-center", targets: [1, 2, 3] }],
            columns: [
                { data: 'door_id', title: 'DOOR ID', autoWidth: false, visible: false },
                { data: 'brand', title: 'Brand Code', autoWidth: true, searchable: true },
                { data: 'buying_group', title: 'Buying Group', autoWidth: true },
                { data: 'setting_name', title: 'Setting Name', autoWidth: true },
                { data: 'sites', title: 'Site(s)', autoWidth: true, orderable: false },
                { data: 'tracking_weeks', title: 'Tracking Weeks', autoWidth: true }
            ],

            initComplete: function () {
                configFilter(this, [0, 1, 2, 4]);
            }

        });// datatable
        $('#example_length,#example_filter').hide();
                    
    });        

    function configFilter($this, colArray) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            var tableName = $this[0].id;
            var columns = $this.api().columns();
            $.each(colArray, function (i, arg) {
                $('#' + tableName + ' th:eq(' + arg + ')').append('<img src="http://www.icone-png.com/png/39/38556.png" class="filterIcon" onclick="showFilter(event,\'' + tableName + '_' + arg + '\')" />');
            });

            var template = '<div class="modalFilter">' +
                '<div class="modal-content">' +
                '{0}</div>' +
                '<div class="modal-footer">' +
                '<a href="#!" onclick="clearFilter(this, {1}, \'{2}\');"  class=" btn left waves-effect waves-light">Clear</a>' +
                '<a href="#!" onclick="performFilter(this, {1}, \'{2}\');"  class=" btn right waves-effect waves-light">Ok</a>' +
                '</div>' +
                '</div>';
            $.each(colArray, function (index, value) {
                columns.every(function (i) {
                    if (value === i) {

                        var column = this, content = '<input type="text" class="filterSearchText" onkeyup="filterValues(this)" /> <br/>';
                        var columnName = $(this.header()).text().replace(/\s+/g, "_");
                        var distinctArray = [];
                        column.data().each(function (d, j) {
                            if (distinctArray.indexOf(d) == -1) {
                                var id = tableName + "_" + columnName + "_" + j;
                                content += '<div><input type="checkbox" value="' + d + '"  id="' + id + '"/><label for="' + id + '"> ' + d + '</label></div>';
                                distinctArray.push(d);
                            }
                        });
                        var newTemplate = $(template.replace('{0}', content).replace('{1}', value).replace('{1}', value).replace('{2}', tableName).replace('{2}', tableName));
                        $('body').append(newTemplate);
                        modalFilterArray[tableName + "_" + value] = newTemplate;
                        content = '';
                    }
                });
            });
        }, 50);
    }

    var modalFilterArray = {};

    function showFilter(e, index) {
        var table = $('#' + index.split('_')[0]).DataTable();
        var columnIdx = parseInt(index.split('_')[1]);
        var column = table.column(columnIdx);
        var filterContainer = $(modalFilterArray[index]);
        var content = '<input type="text" class="filterSearchText" onkeyup="filterValues(this)" /> <br/>';
        var distinctArray = [];
        var columnMapping = {
                     0: 'brand',
                     1: 'buying_group',
                     2: 'setting_name',
                     3: 'sites',
                     4: 'tracking_weeks'
            };
        var propertyName = columnMapping[columnIdx];

        table.rows({ search: 'applied' }).every(function (rowIdx, tableLoop, rowLoop) {
            //var data = this.data()[columnIdx];
            var data = this.data()[propertyName];
            if (distinctArray.indexOf(data) == -1) {
                var id = index + "_" + rowIdx;
                content += '<div><input type="checkbox" value="' + data + '" id="' + id + '"/><label for="' + id + '"> ' + data + '</label></div>';
                distinctArray.push(data);
            }
        });

        filterContainer.find('.modal-content').html(content);

        $('.modalFilter').hide();
        var th = $(e.target).parent();
        var pos = th.offset();
        filterContainer.width(th.width() * 0.75);
        filterContainer.css({ 'left': pos.left, 'top': pos.top }).show();
        $('#mask').show();
        e.stopPropagation();
    }

    function filterValues(node) {
        var searchString = $(node).val(); //.toUpperCase().trim();
        var rootNode = $(node).parent();
        if (searchString == '') {
            rootNode.find('div').show();
        } else {
            rootNode.find("div").hide();
            rootNode.find("div:contains('" + searchString + "')").show();
        }
    }

    function performFilter(node, i, tableId) {            
        var rootNode = $(node).parent().parent();
        var searchString = '', counter = 0;
        rootNode.find('input:checkbox').each(function (index, checkbox) 
        {
            if (checkbox.checked) 
            {
                searchString += (counter == 0) ? checkbox.value : '|' + checkbox.value;                    
                counter++;
            }
        });            
        
        $('#' + tableId).DataTable().column(i).search(searchString, true, false).draw();
        
        rootNode.hide();
        $('#mask').hide();
    }

    function clearFilter(node, i, tableId) {
        var rootNode = $(node).parent().parent();
        rootNode.find(".filterSearchText").val('');
        rootNode.find('input:checkbox').each(function (index, checkbox) {
            checkbox.checked = false;
            $(checkbox).parent().show();
        });
        $('#' + tableId).DataTable().column(i).search('', true, false).draw();
        rootNode.hide();
        $('#mask').hide();
    }

</script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="mask"></div>
 <table id="example" class="bordered material-table centered striped green lighten-1"> 
 </table>
 </body>
 </html>

In the DOOR_MANAGEMENT Controller class, the method for loading data is shown below:
     public IActionResult LoadDoors(int draw = 1, int start = 0, int length = 10, string search = "", string FilterByColumn = "", string ASC_DSEC = "")
       {
        List<DoorDetails> ListData = new List<DoorDetails>();            
        int recordsTotal = 0;

        DateTime aDate = DateTime.Now;

        DoorDetails dm = new DoorDetails();
        dm.door_id = 1;            
        dm.brand = "BM";
        dm.buying_group = "Silly USA";
        dm.setting_name = "Settings1";            
        dm.datamodel = 13;
        dm.tracking_weeks = 1;           

        DoorDetails dm1 = new DoorDetails();
        dm1.door_id = 2;           
        dm1.brand = "NB";
        dm1.buying_group = "John USA";
        dm1.setting_name = "Settings2";            
        dm1.datamodel = 16;
        dm1.tracking_weeks = 14;           

        DoorDetails dm11 = new DoorDetails();
        dm11.door_id = 3;           ;
        dm11.brand = "JA";
        dm11.buying_group = "Mathew UK";
        dm11.setting_name = "Settings 3";            
        dm11.datamodel = 17;
        dm11.tracking_weeks = 45;           

        ListData.Add(dm);
        ListData.Add(dm1);
        ListData.Add(dm11);

        recordsTotal = ListData.Count();      
      
        var jsonData = new { draw = draw, recordsFiltered = recordsTotal, 
                       recordsTotal = recordsTotal, data = ListData };
        return Ok(jsonData);
    }

And the DoorDetails Model class is shown below:
     namespace AMD_WEB.Models
     {
       public class DoorDetails
        {        
          public int door_id { get; set; }                 
          public string brand { get; set; }        
          public string buying_group { get; set; }      
          public string setting_name { get; set; }       
          public int? datamodel { get; set; }
          public int? tracking_weeks { get; set; }                   

       }
   }

The problem is in the below section of code:
   function performFilter(node, i, tableId) {            
        var rootNode = $(node).parent().parent();
        var searchString = '', counter = 0;
        rootNode.find('input:checkbox').each(function (index, checkbox) 
        {
            if (checkbox.checked) 
            {
                searchString += (counter == 0) ? checkbox.value : '|' + checkbox.value;                    
                counter++;
            }
        });            
        
        $('#' + tableId).DataTable().column(i).search(searchString, true, 
        false).draw(); // HERE SEARCH IS NOT WORKING
        
        rootNode.hide();
        $('#mask').hide();
    }

How to correct it ? I want to filter the datatable when clicking OK on the filter menu.

Based on my observation, as your DataTable is server-side processing, the column(i).search() API will also be server-side processing, which means the data searching is performed on the server-side instead of the front-end side. So you need to pass the correct search criteria in the data function and your API is required to implement the searching logic.

Besides that, what if the user tries to filter with multiple columns, based on your API, I see that it only accepts the filter by one column.


Use a array to store the selected checkbox and column ,then we should edit showFilter,performFilter ,clearFilter three
functions,add the array param to the Action in resetDataTable function.I updown all code in in case there's someting missing:


here is the script code:
<script>
     var searchStr = "";//store the selected checkbox value
     var myDataTable = {};//store the initialize table
     var orderColumn = ''//selected column for custom filter
     var filterArr = [];//store checkbox and column
     var columnMapping = {
         0: 'brand',
         1: 'buying_group',
         2: 'setting_name',
         3: 'sites',
         4: 'tracking_weeks'
     };
     $(document).ready(function () {
         resetDataTable();//initialize table
         $('#example_length,#example_filter').hide();

     });

     function configFilter($this, colArray) {
         setTimeout(function () {
             var tableName = $this[0].id;
             var columns = $this.api().columns();
             $.each(colArray, function (i, arg) {
                 $('#' + tableName + ' th:eq(' + arg + ')').append('<img src="http://www.icone-png.com/png/39/38556.png" class="filterIcon" onclick="showFilter(event,\'' + tableName + '_' + arg + '\')" />');
             });

             var template = '<div class="modalFilter">' +
                 '<div class="modal-content">' +
                 '{0}</div>' +
                 '<div class="modal-footer">' +
                 '<a href="#!" onclick="clearFilter(this, {1}, \'{2}\');"  class=" btn left waves-effect waves-light">Clear</a>' +
                 '<a href="javascript:;" onclick="performFilter(this, {1}, \'{2}\');"  class=" btn right waves-effect waves-light">Ok</a>' +
                 '</div>' +
                 '</div>';
             $.each(colArray, function (index, value) {
                 columns.every(function (i) {
                     if (value === i) {
                         var column = this, content = '<input type="text" class="filterSearchText" onkeyup="filterValues(this)" /> <br/>';
                         var columnName = $(this.header()).text().replace(/\s+/g, "_");
                         var distinctArray = [];
                         column.data().each(function (d, j) {
                             if (distinctArray.indexOf(d) == -1) {
                                 var id = tableName + "_" + columnName + "_" + j;
                                 content += '<div><input type="checkbox" value="' + d + '"  id="' + id + '"/><label for="' + id + '"> ' + d + '</label></div>';
                                 distinctArray.push(d);
                             }
                         });
                         var newTemplate = $(template.replace('{0}', content).replace('{1}', value).replace('{1}', value).replace('{2}', tableName).replace('{2}', tableName));
                         $('body').append(newTemplate);
                         modalFilterArray[tableName + "_" + value] = newTemplate;
                         content = '';
                     }
                 });
             });
         }, 50);
     }

     var modalFilterArray = {};

     function showFilter(e, index) {
       
         var table = $('#' + index.split('_')[0]).DataTable();
         var columnIdx = parseInt(index.split('_')[1]);
         var column = table.column(columnIdx);
         var filterContainer = $(modalFilterArray[index]);
         var content = '<input type="text" class="filterSearchText" onkeyup="filterValues(this)" /> <br/>';
         var distinctArray = [];
        
         var propertyName = columnMapping[columnIdx];

         table.rows({ search: 'applied' }).every(function (rowIdx, tableLoop, rowLoop) {
             //var data = this.data()[columnIdx];
             var data = this.data()[propertyName];
             var searchStr = "";
             var searchArr = [];
             console.log(filterArr);
             filterArr.forEach(function(item){
                 if (item.column == propertyName) { 
                     searchStr = item.searchStr;
                 }
                 
             })
             if (searchStr.indexOf('|') < 0) {
                 searchArr = [searchStr]
             } else { 
                 searchArr = searchStr.split("|")
             }
           
             if (distinctArray.indexOf(data) == -1) {
                 var id = index + "_" + rowIdx;
                 if (searchArr.indexOf(data) >= 0) {
                   
                     content += '<div><input  checked type="checkbox" value="' + data + '" id="' + id + '"/><label for="' + id + '" > ' + data + '</label></div>';
                    
                 } else {
                     content += '<div><input type="checkbox" value="' + data + '" id="' + id + '"/><label for="' + id + '"> ' + data + '</label></div>';
                 }
                 
                 distinctArray.push(data);
             }
         });

         filterContainer.find('.modal-content').html(content);

         $('.modalFilter').hide();
         var th = $(e.target).parent();
         var pos = th.offset();
         filterContainer.width(th.width() * 0.75);
         filterContainer.css({ 'left': pos.left, 'top': pos.top }).show();
         $('#mask').show();
         e.stopPropagation();
     }

     function filterValues(node) {
         var searchString = $(node).val(); //.toUpperCase().trim();
         var rootNode = $(node).parent();
         if (searchString == '') {
             rootNode.find('div').show();
         } else {
             rootNode.find("div").hide();
             rootNode.find("div:contains('" + searchString + "')").show();
         }
     }

     function performFilter(node, i, tableId) {
         
         orderColumn = columnMapping[i];//set value

         searchStr = ""; //clear
       
         var rootNode = $(node).parent().parent();
         var searchString = '', counter = 0;
         rootNode.find('input:checkbox').each(function (index, checkbox) {
             if (checkbox.checked) {
                 searchString += (counter == 0) ? checkbox.value : '|' + checkbox.value;
                 counter++;
             }
         });
         searchStr =  rootNode.find('.filterSearchText').val()||searchString;//set value
         var isIn = false
         filterArr.forEach( function (item, index) {//exsit
             if (item.column == orderColumn) { 
                 item.searchStr = searchStr;
                 isIn = true;
             }
         })
         if (!isIn) { 
             filterArr.push({
                 column: orderColumn,
                 searchStr: searchStr
             })
         }
         console.log(filterArr);
         myDataTable.destroy();//destory table
         $('#example').empty();//clear talbe in html
         $('.modalFilter').remove();//remove  all the modalFilter
         resetDataTable();//initialize table
         rootNode.hide();
         $('#mask').hide();
     }

     //initialize table method
     function resetDataTable() {
         myDataTable = $("#example").DataTable({
             serverSide: true,
             sortable: true,
             filter: true,
             searchDelay: 1000,
             lengthMenu: [[5, 10, 50, -1], [5, 10, 50, "All"]],
             language: { searchPlaceholder: "Brand, Buying Group" },
             scrollCollapse: true,
             ajax: {
                 url: '@Url.Action("LoadDoors", "Home")',// your method is doesn't work,So I use this.
                 //URL: "/Home/LoadDoors"
                 type: 'POST',
                 datatype: 'json',
                

                 headers: { 'RequestVerificationToken': 'your json token' },
             
                 data: (d) => {
                    
               return { draw: d.draw, start: d.start, length: d.length, search: d.search.value, FilterByColumn: d.columns[d.order[0].column].data, ASC_DSEC: d.order[0].dir, filterArr: filterArr }      
                 },
                 // beforeSend: () => { ShowLoader(); },
                 // complete: () => { HideLoader(); },
                 dataSrc: (json) => {
                     json = json.data;
                     for (var i = 0, ien = json.length; i < ien; i++) {

                         json[i]['sites'] = '<button style="height:25px;width:60px"> Site </button>';
                     }
                     return json;
                 }
             },
             columnDefs: [{ className: "dt-center", targets: [1, 2, 3] }],
             columns: [
                 { data: 'door_id', title: 'DOOR ID', autoWidth: false, visible: false },
                 { data: 'brand', title: 'Brand Code', autoWidth: true, searchable: true },
                 { data: 'buying_group', title: 'Buying Group', autoWidth: true },
                 { data: 'setting_name', title: 'Setting Name', autoWidth: true },
                 { data: 'sites', title: 'Site(s)', autoWidth: true, orderable: false },
                 { data: 'tracking_weeks', title: 'Tracking Weeks', autoWidth: true }
             ],

             initComplete: function () {
                 configFilter(this, [0, 1, 2, 4]);
             }

         });// datatable
     }
     function clearFilter(node, i, tableId) {
         var rootNode = $(node).parent().parent();
         rootNode.find(".filterSearchText").val('');
         rootNode.find('input:checkbox').each(function (index, checkbox) {
             checkbox.checked = false;
             $(checkbox).parent().show();
         });
      
         orderColumn = columnMapping[i];//set value
         searchStr = '' || rootNode.find('.filterSearchText').val()//set value
         filterArr.forEach(function (item, index) {//exsit
             if (item.column == orderColumn) {
                 item.searchStr = "";
             }
         })
         myDataTable.destroy();//destory table
         $('#example').empty();//clear talbe in html
         $('.modalFilter').remove();//remove  all the modalFilter
         resetDataTable();//initialize table
         
         rootNode.hide();
         $('#mask').hide();
     }

 </script>

2.The action process data.
1).create a filterArr model :
public class filterArr
{
    public string column { get; set; }
    public string searchStr { get; set; }
}

2).Action (your project should have use database,so I do not write processing logic,you can see:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/where-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16 ):
public IActionResult LoadDoors(List<filterArr> filterArr,string FilterByColumn ="")//filter from colum require two params,
{
    string result = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(filterArr);
    for (int i = 0; i < filterArr.Count(); i++)
    {

        Console.Write(filterArr[i].column);

    }
    List<DoorDetails> ListData = new List<DoorDetails>();
    int recordsTotal = 0;

    DateTime aDate = DateTime.Now;

    DoorDetails dm = new DoorDetails();
    dm.door_id = 1;
    dm.brand = "BM";
    dm.buying_group = "Silly USA";
    dm.setting_name = "Settings1";
    dm.datamodel = 13;
    dm.tracking_weeks = 1;

    DoorDetails dm1 = new DoorDetails();
    dm1.door_id = 2;
    dm1.brand = "NB";
    dm1.buying_group = "John USA";
    dm1.setting_name = "Settings2";
    dm1.datamodel = 16;
    dm1.tracking_weeks = 14;

    DoorDetails dm11 = new DoorDetails();
    dm11.door_id = 3; ;
    dm11.brand = "JA";
    dm11.buying_group = "Mathew UK";
    dm11.setting_name = "Settings3";
    dm11.datamodel = 17;
    dm11.tracking_weeks = 45;

    ListData.Add(dm);
    ListData.Add(dm1);
    ListData.Add(dm11);
       
    
    recordsTotal = ListData.Count();

    var jsonData = new
    {
        draw = 1,
        recordsFiltered = recordsTotal,
        recordsTotal = recordsTotal,
        data = ListData
    };
    return Ok(jsonData);
}

The result are:



Hi @XieMan The filtering is not working at all with this new code. I have made it work with your previous answer. Filtering is working with the previous code. I just changed some code in LoadDoors method and it is working. But Checkbox in the filter menu has to be in checked state for the already filtered item. Can you write that code only ??? Just remove the new code above and please explain me how to do the checkbox checked item for the already checked data ?? Thanks for the helps.

Do you mean to write the filter logic for action LoodDoors? I think it too complex to operate fixed data , we usually work with data from databases.

Hi @XieMan thanks your code is working now. But 1 small issue. When filtering the column "tracking_weeks", it is not maintaining the checkbox checked state if already filtered. But other columns are working properly. What happened to "tracking_weeks" ?

You can check if the data type matches,whether it is a string or  a number , then convert it.

1.Draw method doesn't work,we shoud destory the table  and then initialize table.
2."searchString" can not be passed to the method because no field to received.I defind two variables to pass the parameters.
I copy your code meet some problems,I don't know if you have the same problem,so I put comments on all my changes. I hope this can help you.
controller.cs:
public IActionResult LoadDoors(  string FilterStrings,  string FilterOrder= "")//filter from colum require two params,
{
     List<DoorDetails> ListData = new List<DoorDetails>();
     int recordsTotal = 0;
 
     DateTime aDate = DateTime.Now;
 
     DoorDetails dm = new DoorDetails();
     dm.door_id = 1;
     dm.brand = "BM";
     dm.buying_group = "Silly USA";
     dm.setting_name = "Settings1";
     dm.datamodel = 13;
     dm.tracking_weeks = 1;
 
     DoorDetails dm1 = new DoorDetails();
     dm1.door_id = 2;
     dm1.brand = "NB";
     dm1.buying_group = "John USA";
     dm1.setting_name = "Settings2";
     dm1.datamodel = 16;
     dm1.tracking_weeks = 14;
 
     DoorDetails dm11 = new DoorDetails();
     dm11.door_id = 3; ;
     dm11.brand = "JA";
     dm11.buying_group = "Mathew UK";
     dm11.setting_name = "Settings3";
     dm11.datamodel = 17;
     dm11.tracking_weeks = 45;
 
     ListData.Add(dm);
     ListData.Add(dm1);
     ListData.Add(dm11);
     //this code to processing data filter by page
     if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(FilterStrings)) {
         for (int i = 0; i < ListData.Count(); i++)
         {
             Console.Write(FilterStrings.Contains(ListData[i].GetType().GetProperty(FilterOrder)?.GetValue(ListData[i])?.ToString() ?? ""));
 
             if (!FilterStrings.Contains(ListData[i].setting_name))
             {
                 ListData.Remove(ListData[i]);
             }
 
         }
     }
 
     recordsTotal = ListData.Count();
 
     var jsonData = new
     {
         draw = 1,
         recordsFiltered = recordsTotal,
         recordsTotal = recordsTotal,
         data = ListData
     };
     return Ok(jsonData);
}

.cshtml:
 @model WebApplication1.Models.DoorDetails
 
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
}
 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 
     <link href=https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css
          type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen,projection" /> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href=https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.7/css/materialize.min.css />
    <script src=https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.js></script>
     <script src=https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js></script> 
   @*  <script src="~/js/materialize.min.js"></script> *@
 
    <style>
        table.dataTable th {
            border-bottom: 1px solid #333;
            border-right: 1px solid #333;
        }
 
        table.dataTable td {
            border-bottom: 1px solid #333;
            border-right: 1px solid #333;
        }
 
        .filterIcon {
            height: 16px;
            width: 16px;
            background: red; /* have no icon     */
        }
 
        .modalFilter {
            display: none;
            height: auto;
            background: #FFF;
            border: solid 1px #ccc;
            padding: 8px;
            position: absolute;
            z-index: 1001;
        }
 
            .modalFilter .modal-content {
                max-height: 250px;
                overflow-y: auto;
            }
 
            .modalFilter .modal-footer {
                background: #FFF;
                height: 35px;
                padding-top: 6px;
            }
 
            .modalFilter .btn {
                padding: 0 1em;
                height: 28px;
                line-height: 28px;
                text-transform: none;
            }
 
        #mask {
            display: none;
            background: transparent;
            position: fixed;
            left: 0;
            top: 0;
            z-index: 1;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            opacity: 1000;
        }
    </style>
 
    <script>
        var searchStr = "";//store the selected checkbox value
        var myDataTable = {};//store the initialize table
        var orderColumn = ''//selected column for custom filter
        $(document).ready(function () {
            resetDataTable();//initialize table
            $('#example_length,#example_filter').hide();
 
        });
 
        function configFilter($this, colArray) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                var tableName = $this[0].id;
                var columns = $this.api().columns();
                $.each(colArray, function (i, arg) {
                    $('#' + tableName + ' th:eq(' + arg + ')').append('<img src=http://www.icone-png.com/png/39/38556.png class="filterIcon" onclick="showFilter(event,\'' + tableName + '_' + arg + '\')" />');
                });
 
                var template = '<div class="modalFilter">' +
                    '<div class="modal-content">' +
                    '{0}</div>' +
                    '<div class="modal-footer">' +
                    '<a href="#!" onclick="clearFilter(this, {1}, \'{2}\');"  class=" btn left waves-effect waves-light">Clear</a>' +
                    '<a href="javascript:;" onclick="performFilter(this, {1}, \'{2}\');"  class=" btn right waves-effect waves-light">Ok</a>' +
                    '</div>' +
                    '</div>';
                $.each(colArray, function (index, value) {
                    columns.every(function (i) {
                        if (value === i) {
 
                            var column = this, content = '<input type="text" class="filterSearchText" onkeyup="filterValues(this)" /> <br/>';
                            var columnName = $(this.header()).text().replace(/\s+/g, "_");
                            var distinctArray = [];
                            column.data().each(function (d, j) {
                                if (distinctArray.indexOf(d) == -1) {
                                    var id = tableName + "_" + columnName + "_" + j;
                                    content += '<div><input type="checkbox" value="' + d + '"  id="' + id + '"/><label for="' + id + '"> ' + d + '</label></div>';
                                    distinctArray.push(d);
                                }
                            });
                            var newTemplate = $(template.replace('{0}', content).replace('{1}', value).replace('{1}', value).replace('{2}', tableName).replace('{2}', tableName));
                            $('body').append(newTemplate);
                            modalFilterArray[tableName + "_" + value] = newTemplate;
                            content = '';
                        }
                    });
                });
            }, 50);
        }
 
        var modalFilterArray = {};
 
        function showFilter(e, index) {
            var table = $('#' + index.split('_')[0]).DataTable();
            var columnIdx = parseInt(index.split('_')[1]);
            var column = table.column(columnIdx);
            var filterContainer = $(modalFilterArray[index]);
            var content = '<input type="text" class="filterSearchText" onkeyup="filterValues(this)" /> <br/>';
            var distinctArray = [];
            var columnMapping = {
                0: 'brand',
                1: 'buying_group',
                2: 'setting_name',
                3: 'sites',
                4: 'tracking_weeks'
            };
            var propertyName = columnMapping[columnIdx];
 
            table.rows({ search: 'applied' }).every(function (rowIdx, tableLoop, rowLoop) {
                //var data = this.data()[columnIdx];
                var data = this.data()[propertyName];
                if (distinctArray.indexOf(data) == -1) {
                    var id = index + "_" + rowIdx;
                    content += '<div><input type="checkbox" value="' + data + '" id="' + id + '"/><label for="' + id + '"> ' + data + '</label></div>';
                    distinctArray.push(data);
                }
            });
 
            filterContainer.find('.modal-content').html(content);
 
            $('.modalFilter').hide();
            var th = $(e.target).parent();
            var pos = th.offset();
            filterContainer.width(th.width() * 0.75);
            filterContainer.css({ 'left': pos.left, 'top': pos.top }).show();
            $('#mask').show();
            e.stopPropagation();
        }
 
        function filterValues(node) {
            var searchString = $(node).val(); //.toUpperCase().trim();
            var rootNode = $(node).parent();
            if (searchString == '') {
                rootNode.find('div').show();
            } else {
                rootNode.find("div").hide();
                rootNode.find("div:contains('" + searchString + "')").show();
            }
        }
 
  
 function performFilter(node, i, tableId) {
    searchStr = ""; //clear
    orderColumn = "";//clear
    var rootNode = $(node).parent().parent();
    var searchString = '', counter = 0;
    rootNode.find('input:checkbox').each(function (index, checkbox) {
        if (checkbox.checked) {
            searchString += (counter == 0) ? checkbox.value : '|' + checkbox.value;
            counter++;
        }
    });
   
     var columnMapping = {
        0: 'brand',
        1: 'buying_group',
        2: 'setting_name',
        3: 'sites',
        4: 'tracking_weeks'
    };
    orderColumn = columnMapping[i];//set value
    searchStr =  rootNode.find('.filterSearchText').val()||searchString;//set value
    
    myDataTable.destroy();//destory table
    $('#example').empty();//clear talbe in html
    $('.modalFilter').remove();//remove  all the modalFilter
    resetDataTable();//initialize table
    rootNode.hide();
    $('#mask').hide();
}
 
        //initialize table method
        function resetDataTable() {
            myDataTable = $("#example").DataTable({
                serverSide: true,
                sortable: true,
                filter: true,
                searchDelay: 1000,
                lengthMenu: [[5, 10, 50, -1], [5, 10, 50, "All"]],
                language: { searchPlaceholder: "Brand, Buying Group" },
                scrollCollapse: true,
                ajax: {
                    url: '@Url.Action("LoadDoors", "Home")',// your method is doesn't work,So I use this.
                    //URL: "/Home/LoadDoors"
                    type: 'GET',
                    datatype: 'json',
                    headers: { 'RequestVerificationToken': 'your json token' },
                    data: (d) => {
                        console.log(d)
                        return { draw: d.draw, start: d.start, length: d.length, search: d.search.value, FilterByColumn: d.columns[d.order[0].column].data, ASC_DSEC: d.order[0].dir, FilterStrings: searchStr, FilterOrder: orderColumn }
                    },
                    //beforeSend: () => { ShowLoader(); },
                    //complete: () => { HideLoader(); },
                    dataSrc: (json) => {
                        json = json.data;
                        for (var i = 0, ien = json.length; i < ien; i++) {
 
                            json[i]['sites'] = '<button style="height:25px;width:60px"> Site </button>';
                        }
                        return json;
                    }
                },
                columnDefs: [{ className: "dt-center", targets: [1, 2, 3] }],
                columns: [
                    { data: 'door_id', title: 'DOOR ID', autoWidth: false, visible: false },
                    { data: 'brand', title: 'Brand Code', autoWidth: true, searchable: true },
                    { data: 'buying_group', title: 'Buying Group', autoWidth: true },
                    { data: 'setting_name', title: 'Setting Name', autoWidth: true },
                    { data: 'sites', title: 'Site(s)', autoWidth: true, orderable: false },
                    { data: 'tracking_weeks', title: 'Tracking Weeks', autoWidth: true }
                ],
 
                initComplete: function () {
                    configFilter(this, [0, 1, 2, 4]);
                }
 
            });// datatable
        }
        function clearFilter(node, i, tableId) {
var rootNode = $(node).parent().parent();
rootNode.find(".filterSearchText").val('');
rootNode.find('input:checkbox').each(function (index, checkbox) {
    checkbox.checked = false;
    $(checkbox).parent().show();
});
var columnMapping = {
    0: 'brand',
    1: 'buying_group',
    2: 'setting_name',
    3: 'sites',
    4: 'tracking_weeks'
};
orderColumn = columnMapping[i];//set value

 searchStr = '' || rootNode.find('.filterSearchText').val()//set value

    myDataTable.destroy();//destory table
    $('#example').empty();//clear talbe in html
    $('.modalFilter').remove();//remove  all the modalFilter
    resetDataTable();//initialize table
    
    rootNode.hide();
    $('#mask').hide();
}
 
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="mask"></div>
    <table id="example" class="bordered material-table centered striped green lighten-1">
    </table>
</body>
</html>

The results are :



Hi @XieMan Thanks for the help. But the filter is working only for first time. After that it is not working. From second time onwards, when trying to filter any other column, even I am not able to tick the check boxes in the filter menu. In the filter menu, tick more than 1 check boxes and click OK, the datatable is not filtering. Also, CLEAR button is also not working. One more point is, after filteration, when click on the filter icon, the checked box will be in checked state for already filtered item. Could you please look at these issues ?? Thanks very much.

Hi @XieMan, there is another issue also, in my question, there is a LoadDoors method in the DOOR_MANAGEMENT controller. There is a argument named "FilterByColumn" and we need that for sorting the Column of DataTable. Kindly consider that also.

I edit my answer .you can only change the clearFilter and performFilter function.1.When method draw is called ,you creat anthor modalFilter dialog,so you click the checkbox does not work,so After we destory it ,we should remove all the modalFilter html.
2.I think the criteria have changed after filtering,so there is no need to select all of them.
I3. don't give your idea because I think your project should have use database , your can use sql statment sort so easy.
you can see:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-order-by-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Hi @XieMan. Thanks for your reply. But this is not working for filtering more than 1 value of a column. Suppose, I opened the filtering menu for "Brand Code" and I checked "NB" and "JA" then click ok. It is not working.  I tried to filter for "Setting Name" and I chose "Setting3" in the filtering menu. But it is not filtering as expected. Kindly correct these issues. Thanks very much for your efforts.
